# Cannot change port of Vaadin's "second" Tomcat

Tags: webpack, port, vaadin

We set up a simple Vaadin project (basically just a copy from Vaadin's initializr) which fails to start on one host where port 8081 is already in use and which cannot be freed up for compliance reasons.

During start-up, I first see Tomcat being fired up on the port I expect it to be, i.e. the one configured by `server.port` in the application settings. However, then "another" Tomcat shows up on port 8081:

(though I suspect it's the same one, just an additional port being opened)
[image]

At first, I suspected this to be related to webpack so I tried changing its config in webpack.config.js
[image]

but this didn't do anything at all and the "second" Tomcat still started on 8081 - even with `mvn clean && rm webpack.generated.js` before building & starting. I'm clueless about webpack, so maybe I made a mistake here?

Also considered Vaadin might hold control over that port, with 8081 being the default, so I grep'ed but could not find anything standing out as a good match to me.

What surprises me most is that I did not find anything at all when searching and this (default port settings conflicting with ports already being in use) simply does not seem to be a problem for anyone else - which seems very odd to me. So I guess I'm just searching for the wrong keywords. Would someone please point me to documentation where this is explained or a similar post elsewhere?

Comment: Thats odd. How are you running the app? what command

Comment: I run it with "mvn spring-boot:run" usually with a complete rebuild before, just to make sure, so I tend to run "mvn clean package && mvn spring-boot:run".
What specifically do you mean with "That's odd" - by any chance the presence of the second port being opened ?

Comment: What version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I just started a new project with Initializr. In my `application.properties` file, I have the line `server.port=${PORT:8085}` and it starts up tomcat on 8085 as expected.

Comment: I'm on Vaadin 22.0.5.
I can change "the" port for "the" server via server.port (I'm actually using application.yml but that shouldn't matter) and I do see that port being used during the start-up phase when looking at the log. However, there's another port being opened up, see image in the post, which then causes the conflict and that "port doesn't seem to care" about server.port, hence my assumption it was a different tool opening that second port, e.g. webpack.

Comment: If it's an empty project (no sensitive code) do you mind sharing the project as a zip? so I can take a look at it. Never experienced such.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not an empty project. It inherits from a company-parent-pom and, without it, simply does not make sense. On the plus side, I just found the culprit: one of the company in-house dependencies is to blame, at least partially. When commenting it out (because it's not strictly needed yet), this weird additional port-opening disappears. I'll dive deeper into that dependency and figure out what's going on there. For now, I'll assume the problem lies solely with that dependency. Thank you for your help!